# JQuery animate div entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a webpage with a div container that contains the main content, and inside it there is a div that should appear when I put my mouse in the container. This is the code that I tried:

```
var running=0;
                var running2=0;
                $('div.container').mouseenter(function() 
                {
                    if (running==0) 
                    {
                        running=1;
                        $('div.rightcontainer').css("margin-right",-350)
                        .animate({marginRight:0}, 750, function(){running=0;});
                    }
                }
                );



                $('div.container').mouseleave(function() {
                    if (running2==0) {
                    running2=1;
                    $('div.rightcontainer').css("margin-right",0)
                    .animate({marginRight:-350}, 750, function(){running2=0;});
                    }
                });
```

This code works:

```
$('div.container').mouseenter(function() {
                    console.log('trigger');
                    $("div.rightcontainer")
                    .css("visibility","visible")
                    .css("margin-right",-$("div.rightcontainer").width())
                    .animate({
                        marginRight:0
                    }, 1200); 
                });

                $('div.container').mouseleave(function() {
                    console.log('leave');
                    $("div.rightcontainer")
                    .css("visibility","visible")
                    .css("margin-right", "320") 
                    .animate({
                        marginRight:-350
                    }, 1200);
                });
```

However, the problem is that if the mouse enters multiple times, the object keeps entering and exiting.

Edit:

The .one() only does it once, what I mean is in a way it stacks all the enters and exits and performs the animation that many times.

the .stop() solution was better, however the animation would jump to the end from wherever it was. If there is a way for, if the mouse leaves the container mid-animation, for the animaiton to stop where it is and animate back the other way?

Here is a JSFiddle with a simplified version of the website. The container is anything below the navbar. http://jsfiddle.net/yEzXp/

Comment: This is the type of question that should always come with a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Okay I will keep that in mind. Thanks, I didn't know about JS Fiddles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .stop()

```
$('div.container').mouseenter(function() {
    $("div.rightcontainer")
    .stop(true, true)
    .css("visibility","visible")
    .css("margin-right",-$("div.rightcontainer").width())
    .animate({
        marginRight:0
    }, 1200); 
});

$('div.container').mouseleave(function() {
    $("div.rightcontainer")
    .stop(true, true)
    .css("visibility","visible")
    .css("margin-right", "320") 
    .animate({
        marginRight:-350
    }, 1200);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I looked up .stop and found i needed it to be true, false